# Azure, do we need Web Application Firewall (WAF)?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

Made a rather complex Asp.Net Core (2) App for a NGO, deployed on Azure, do we need WAF? 
Thanks for your answer(s).

(Got the idea that most providers offer it for free. Money is a bit of an issue for the NGO).

Comment: This is a bit like asking if you need antivirus software on Mac or Linux. Azure has standard network controls that should prevent things like DDoS, simply to protect itself. However, if your app is exposed to the internet, it's always vulnerable. Additionally, a WAF generally blocks things that a standard network firewall wouldn't concern itself with. Whether you need a WAF is 100% a function of how much risk you're willing to assume. The lack of one doesn't mean you'll get hacked, but the potential is greater without one.

Comment: In case of antivirus software on Windows, Mac or Linux, I have (full) control what I’m doing, so I might not need it. In case of a cloud application I got less control. So perhaps the question should be something like “How vulnerable is a standard (one created with a Visual Studio template) Application?”

Comment: You're kidding yourself if you think you have any more control of your desktop. The point was that all systems are vulnerable, but not necessarily as much or to the same attack vectors. This is the same here. Are you quite as vulnerable in Azure as you might be just throwing a server outside with no network security? No. But, there's still attack vectors Azure will not protect you from. You could be just fine running your Android device without malware protection, and you could be just fine without a WAF. Or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I'm afraid that your question is not suitable for asking on StackOverflow, which seems to be not a technical issue about coding as my view. [Infomation Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) forum is more suited to ask for your needs, I think so.</s>

However,  Considering for reducing the cost for using some specifical secure services or features, such as WAF, you can directly realize some simple features by using [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2) as a simple secure middleware for your app, or search on GitHub to find some opensource components that features could satisfy your needs to integrate into your app.

As references, there are two GitHub repos which you can refer to.

1. [dustinmoris/Firewall](https://github.com/dustinmoris/Firewall)
2. [saineshwar/Secure-ASP.NET-Core-MVC-Application](https://github.com/saineshwar/Secure-ASP.NET-Core-MVC-Application)

Hope it helps.